# A better way to build factory using factory_girl in cucumber

Tags: cucumber, factory-bot

I am using cucumber and factory_girl in a rails 2.3.9 project.

Here is one of the givens in one of my features.

```
Given a user with first_name "Mary" and last_name "Jane"
```

I started building the regex where I could capture following items.

```
model = user 
first_name = "Mary"
last_name = "Jane"
Factory(:user, :first_name => 'Mary', :last_name => "Jane")
```

Given how popular cucumber and factory_girl are, I'm sure there must be a better way rather than me reinventing the wheel.

What's a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/284805810/gimme-three-steps